# Android: Find nearby points in my location in the map

Tags: android, gps, maps, latitude-longitude

I have a table in database where there are points in map recorded by latitude and longitude.

How can I determinate which of these points are nearby my detected location? The user will give the maximum distance its wants to walk to go this place.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate it yourself: Take a look at [this](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) explanation of the *[haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)*. It explains the math and has a working Javascript example.

Alternatively, it seems there is also a [builtin Android function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo%28android.location.Location%29) you can use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Junuxx! It helped so much! =)